# is there a way to disable in app activity with adb?

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to use adb to disable an activity in the app?
the activity I am trying to disable is known as `com.samsung.android.app.music.activity.SettingTabsActivity`

I am trying to use the command `pm uninstall --user 0 com.samsung.android.app.music.activity.SettingTabsActivity`

But end up getting the error not installed for 0

I looked in the package disabler app and yes, there IS a package known as that but it says different for the adb command i have used...

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
./adb shell pm disable com.samsung.android.app.music.activity/.SettingTabsActivity
```

Comment: Although this seems to be right I seem to get the error saying
 "exception occured while executing"

Is there a possible way to avoid this?

Comment: sorry for asking again but earlier when i did this i had gotten an error saying exception occured while executing... any reason for this?

Comment: I will look at this if i get free time.